# Cannot left join a table multiple times

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, "Operative_processes" and "Products" (results of the processes). The products have a field called "type", which goes from 0 up to 2, a field for the weight and a field with the process that made that product. I need to have a table in which every process is listed with the weight of products of every type.

I looked for similar questions on the internet and looks like that the solution to my problem is just putting the aliases to every field I need to take from the other table.

Since this point, the code still works

````
SELECT id, xxx, sum(database.products.weight) as 'type 0'
FROM database.operative_processes
LEFT JOIN database.products 
ON database.operative_processes.id = database.products.operative_process_that_made_me and product_type = 0```
````

But when I try to put aliases to do the multiple join, I get the 1054 error:

```
SELECT id, xxx, sum(database.products.weight) as 'type 0', 
        sum(database.products.weight) as 'type 1',   
        sum(database.products.weight) as 'type 2'
FROM database.operative_processes
    LEFT JOIN database.products as 'type 0'
        ON database.operative_processes.id = database.products.operative_process_that_made_me 
        and product_type = 0
    LEFT JOIN database.products as 'type 1'
        ON database.operative_processes.id = 
            database.products.operative_process_that_made_me and product_type = 1
    LEFT JOIN database.products as 'type 2'
        ON database.operative_processes.id = database.products.operative_process_that_made_me 
        and product_type = 2
```

Basically, the error starts occurring when I put the "as 'type 0' " after "LEFT JOIN database.products", without the alias it still would work

I'm using MySQL 8.0

Comment: Consider NOT using spaced in table/column names or aliases

Comment: A slightly shorter naming convension all around would also help

Comment: You've edited the code in the question several times, and every time you still have syntax errors from mismatched quotes.  Try moving the quotes entirely and just using names that don't try to have spaces.  You're also trying to give the same aliases to your tables *and* your columns, which is all but guaranteed to cause confusion.  And where/how does the query even *use* any of the joined data?

Comment: @David: i mismatched quotes because i am pratically writing the query back again from 0, but i checked yet and i'm sure i didn't wrote it bad on my consolle. 

Is using the same aliases bad? I thought it was the point of the multiple join (by linking the table to the alias itself). So, how do i link it? 
I need to do something like 

|| process_id | sum the weight of products with same process_id and prod_type = 0 | sum the weight of products with same process_id and prod_type = 1 | sum the weight of products with same process_id and prod_type = 2||,

Comment: @VincenzoCostantini: *"but i checked yet and i'm sure i didn't wrote it bad on my consolle"* - Why introduce an unnecessary point of failure?  Instead of asking about code that **probably looks like** the code you're using, copy/paste the **actual** code you're using.  *"Is using the same aliases bad?"* - It could certainly be confusing.  And if you're struggling to make your code work, making it more confusing won't help you.  Why do you need both a table **and** a column to be named `'type 0'`, for example?  Maybe call the column `'sum 0'` instead? Why do you need spaces in the names at all?

Comment: @David i left the office now, i will post the exact code tomorrow. 
Anyway, i wrote it again because the variable names are italian and it's full of unnecessary data, the code i wrote summarized it. 
Morover, i told that i thought that giving the same aliases was mandatory to link the field i wanted to link

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your space-containing aliases with backticks, not single quotes. Try this.

```
FROM database.operative_processes as op
LEFT JOIN database.products as `type 0` 
        ON op.id = `type 0`.operative_process_that_made_me 
       AND `type 0`.product_type = 0
```

But those kinds of aliases are tremendously hard to read. Try using `type_0` rather than `type 0` as an alias. Like this and skip the backticks. They're not portable to other makes of DBMS anyhow.

```
FROM database.operative_processes op
LEFT JOIN database.products as type_0 
        ON op.id = type_0.operative_process_that_made_me 
       AND type_0.product_type = 0
```

**Edit**

The phrase `FROM database.operative_processes op` makes `op` into an alias for that table. I like writing queries that way because the SELECT and ON clauses are more concise.

Comment: Is that mandatory to put a "database name" after the "FROM" statement?
It looks like you declared the table as a variable and used that to extract the column i need.

Comment: Please see my edit. And no, the `database.table.column` format is not mandatory as long as the default database choice (from your connection parameter or a `USE database`) statement is correct.

Comment: Ok, thak you, but i still cannot make the query work. 
The code runs fine until i try to put "AS 'AnyName' " after LEFT JOIN firstTable and before ON database.processes.id = database.products.process_that_made_me

Comment: Use backticks (on the same keyboard key as `~` on my English keyboard) to surround alias names, not `'` quote marks.  And beware the brain damage in word processing programs that substitutes open-quote `‘` and close-quote `’` characters for ordinary `'` quote characters.  Keep trying: you'll get it to work.

Comment: And, when you give any table an alias in a FROM or JOIN clause, you must use that alias, not the table's name,  to refer to it in SELECT and ON clauses.

Comment: I just tried with " as `anyName` " but still won't run.
Thanks for the advise anyway

Comment: So, the code should look like this?
SELECT process.id, process.miscellaneous, sum1, sum2, sum3
FROM process
LEFT JOIN products as sum1 on process.id = product.process_that_made_me and prodType = 0
LEFT JOIN products as sum2 on process.id = product.process_that_made_me and prodType = 1
LEFT JOIN products as sum3 on process.id = product.process_that_made_me and prodType = 2?

Answer (score 1):

It's clear you don't know much about SQL, but maybe these are some hints.

Your SQL:

```
sum(database.products.weight) as 'type 0',
sum(database.products.weight) as 'type 1',
sum(database.products.weight) as 'type 2'
```

You are telling MySQL to select the sum of `database.products.weight` three times and each time giving the result a different name.
But you don't want that, you want to have the sum of `database.products.weight` per `product_type`.
When you join the `products` table multiple times you give them an alias. You should use this alias to select from that table.
For example:

```
sum(`type 0`.weight) as 'type 0',
sum(`type 1`.weight) as 'type 1',
sum(`type 2`.weight) as 'type 2'
```

(use a backtick because you use spaces in your table name aliases)

Joining means you add columns of other tables to the table you select from. But if you do this: `SELECT id` you have no idea which `id` column will be used if there are multiple `id` columns when you join other tables. So always use the table name as well, for example: `SELECT products.id`

Comment: I cannot understand the code you wrote. How can MySQL sum that scores if i don't even give the table to sum the weights from?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the error, but now the sum it's 3x the expected result. The curious think is that the code didn't go wrong until i added the third column, then it goes crazy

```
SELECT distinct verde2021.essiccazioni.id, verde2021.essiccazioni.impianto, sum(prod1.peso) as 'minibud', sum(prod2.peso) as 'normalbud', sum(prod3.peso) as 'bigbud'
 FROM verde2021.essiccazioni 
 LEFT JOIN verde2021.imbustato prod1 on verde2021.essiccazioni.id = prod1.id_processo_padre and `prod1`.`prodotto` = 1
 LEFT JOIN verde2021.imbustato prod2 on verde2021.essiccazioni.id = prod2.id_processo_padre and `prod2`.`prodotto` = 2  
 LEFT JOIN verde2021.imbustato prod3 on verde2021.essiccazioni.id = prod3.id_processo_padre and `prod3`.`prodotto` = 3  

 group by verde2021.essiccazioni.id LIMIT 0, 10000
```

(That's the actual code).
For some reasons, if i delete the third LEFT JOIN row the results are right

EDIT: After some check, i found out that any of the results are right

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily you should ask another question about your incorrect sums.  They come from a so-called combinatorial explosion caused by your JOIN operations. Each JOIN operation in a query creates a result containing every possible combination of rows that meets the ON condition. So if table a has m rows in it and table b has n rows,

```
 SELECT * FROM a JOIN b
```

with no ON condition will give a result with m * n rows in it. This can really mess up SUM and other aggregate operations.

**Pro tip** If you find yourself using `SELECT DISTINCT` in a query that also contains `GROUP BY` and / or aggregating functions like `SUM()` you are very likely doing something wrong. Stop and think.

You want `SUM(prod1.peso)` and the other two SUMs to be correct. The best way to do that is with conditional aggregation.  Your `imbustato` table has a many:1 relationship to your `essiccazioni` table. So this JOIN produces one row per row in your `imbustato` table. You then do the conditional `SUM(IF(i.prodotto = 1, i.peso, 0)` sums on those rows.

```sql
   USE verde2021;

SELECT e.id, e.impianto,
       SUM(IF(i.prodotto = 1, i.peso, 0) minibud,
       SUM(IF(i.prodotto = 2, i.peso, 0) normalbud,
       SUM(IF(i.prodotto = 3, i.peso, 0) bigbud,
       SUM(i.peso) allbud
 FROM essiccazioni e
 LEFT JOIN imbustato i ON e.id = i.id_processo_padre
GROUP BY e.id
LIMIT 0,1000
```

And, you won't double- or triple- count any rows.

Comment: Thank you, looks like you spotted my lack of knowledge about some MySQL keyword and sintax. I fixed the problem by getting a java method that creates an array of objects based on the rows of the database, and i had to do 3 different more querys for every "essiccazioni" row. That has been painful

Answer (score 0):

@O. Jones
I tried your exact code but somehow it didn't worked. I readed a little about if() conditions and i managed to write it by myself.
Now it's working, but i can't tell what's different except aliases

```
    SELECT id, data_fine_essiccazione, 
round(sum(if(imbustato.`prodotto` = 1, imbustato.`peso`, 0)),2) as minibud,
round(sum(if(imbustato.`prodotto` = 2, imbustato.`peso`, 0)),2) as normalbud,
round(sum(if(imbustato.`prodotto` = 3, imbustato.`peso`, 0)),2)  as bigbud
FROM essiccazioni 
left join verde2021.imbustato  on essiccazioni.id = imbustato.id_processo_padre
group by id;
```